# Как правильно употребить словосочетание?

Tags: склонение, управление

«Любить зиму за сказочные персонажи» или «любить зиму за сказочных персонажей»?

Answer (score 1):

Управление существительным ***персонаж*** (выражение одушевленности/ неодушевленности)

**ПЕРСОНАЖ** [вин. п. ед. ч. персонаж; вин. п. мн. ч. **персонажи** (действующие лица) и **персонажей** (люди)]. Ввести в пьесу комический персонаж; Ввести новые **персонажи**; **Чичиков** напоминает многих реальных **персонажей** из нынешней действительности.

Если ориентироваться на это правило, то надо использовать форму **"за сказочные персонажи".**

Примечание

Лучше сказать: Любить зиму с ее сказочными персонажами. (Но надо смотреть по тексту).

Answer (score 0):

*Делать что-то за кого-то* означает делать это **вместо** кого-то. 
Поэтому "любить за кого-то" здесь неуместно. Остается "любить за что-то", то есть *за персонажи* (отвечает на вопрос что?)

Если рассуждать о смысле фразы, то возникает вопрос: разве сказочные персонажи (вообще) характерны только для зимы? Надо бы уточнить: "за связанные с ней сказочные персонажи", на худой конец, "за ее сказочные персонажи"